# Windows Mobile - Compact Framework program as a service?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

What is the best way to have my C# Compact Framework program running in the background on a Windows Mobile device ? I need to respond to different events, such as a text message arriving with a specific content. I would like not to start up any UI when the process is started, but just run in the background until UI is needed.

How can this be done ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create the app as a Console app.  If you need a message pump, you need to call Run without any parameters, and the CF doesn't have that.  OpenNETCF's [Application2 class](http://opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/2105e26d-8657-81a4-f0f7-b569ddab14fa.htm) in the [SDF](http://www.smartdeviceframework.com) does.  At that point you can raise a UI any time by creating and showing a Form as usual.

You cannot create a true service for CE or WinMo with managed code because EE Hosting is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

How about this project?

[managedserviceswm.codeplex.com](http://managedserviceswm.codeplex.com)