# Infinite loop in Sub Main() by calling itself?

Tags: .net, vb.net, console-application

This might be a really stupid question and im looking for your input if this is a bad/good/forbidden approach.

Lets just say i have a console application that i want to run forever.

I just tested this

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Try
            Console.WriteLine(Now())
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    ' Call the routine again
    Main()
    End Sub

End Module
```

This simply prints the current time after sleeping 1 second and will continue to run.

I just want to know if this is a ok or bad way of looping a routine?

Comment: This is infinite recursion and will eventually result in a stack overflow.

Comment: I would rather use a WHILE-loop which can be interrupted with some specific user input.

Comment: @RogerRowland, in other words to much memory will be allocated and it will crash?

Comment: Every time you call a function, stuff is pushed on the stack. As each function finishes, the stack "unwinds" by popping that stuff off. You're never finishing any function and the stack has a limited size. Eventually you will exceed that size and you will crash. Remove the sleep and see what happens.

Comment: What's the purpose, are you trying to simulate a windows service?

Comment: Thanks, that was all i needed to know! You can put it as answer if you want.

Comment: @AaronPalmer no, I thought i had a little solution to a console application, but i will actually have to build a windows service for my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is infinite recursion and will eventually result in a stack overflow.

Every time you call a function, stuff is pushed on the stack. As each function finishes, the stack "unwinds" by popping that stuff off. You're never finishing any function and the stack has a limited size. Eventually you will exceed that size and you will crash.

Remove the sleep and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what machine you run this on.  If it boots a 64-bit operating system and your project's Target CPU setting is "AnyCPU" then it will work okay, the 64-bit jitter will use an optimization called "tail recursion optimization" to turn the recursive call into a jump.  If not then your program will eventually bomb with this web site's name.

No point in taking that risk when you can do this:

```
Sub Main()
    Do
       '' Rest of your code
       ''...
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Running an infinite loop in a console app is definitely a bad idea.  As Roger Rowland stated, it will result in a stack overflow.

If you want something to always be running in the background you could use a Windows Service instead of a console app.

If you need to use a console app, because Windows Services aren't available on all platforms (ie. Compact Framework), you could [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/237223/24908).